# Understand Auto-Boxing in ArrayLists (Big Java Section 7.3)

Tags: java

Java Beginner here. I'm on the section of my book where we talk about `ArrayLists` and my book just gave me a cool example of an `ArrayList` with `Strings`

Now to my surprise it actually says that

> Because numbers are not objects in Java, you cannot directly insert them into arraylists. For example, you cannot form an `ArrayList<double>.`

Instead we need to use wrapper classes for all eight primitive types. This is where my book gives some small examples which seem odd to me, lets take the following.

This is Auto-Boxing which is putting our `d` into an object. I guess we can think of it as `Double d = new Double(29.95);`

```
Double d =  29.95
```

We can unbox it by doing `double x = d;`,
So now `x` is just a value, right?

Now heres where my confusion relies.
I noticed we can do some arithmetics expressions with our `Double` object
say `d = d+1`

My book says

> Here d is Auto-unboxed into a double
>
> We add 1 to it
>
> Then Auto-box the result into a new Double
>
> **Store a reference to the newly created wrapper object in d**

**My Question**

The last part is what I am having trouble understanding. What does this mean? I remember in Chapter four we learned that when we set two objects equal to each other, when we change one the other one gets changed as well ( I believe this was called `by reference`)

On the other hand why would I do arithmetic like this anyway? If we have to unbox then box, this seems super super inefficient. I would say use a normal array in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d = d + 1` where `d` is `Double` essentially means `d = Double.valueOf(d.doubleValue() + 1);`, that is a new value is allocated for the result. Implicitly adding `Double.valueOf` and `d.doubleValue` is essentially what autoboxing is about (it could be `new Double` instead of `Double.valueOf`, but the meaning remains the same).

Similarly `double x = d` means `double x = d.doubleValue()`.

As a good practice I would advise to change autoboxing into explicit type conversion using e.g. `.doubleValue()` and `Double.valueOf`. Any IDE will help you detect those and by explicitly defining the conversions some errors, typically NPE, may become more obvious.

Comment: I see. when we say Double d = 29.95, d is an object right? Not a value? As opposed to double d = 29.95 which is a value?

Comment: Well, it is an object holding a double value

Comment: Is there any real benefit to this? I mean when we set stuff to numbers we generally want to manipulate them in some way. If we make it an object holding a double value we need to do that conversion.

Comment: As I suggested in the answer, I would recommend to explicitly convert. IMHO introducing autoboxing was a wrong design decision.